# Exiting ssh -tt session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, tty

I am executing a script on a remote ssh host as follows:

`ssh -tt $USER@somehost 'bash -s' < ./myscript.sh`

Notice the pseudo tty `-tt` switch.

My problem is that after the script has finished running the ssh session is not ending.  Typing `exit` doesn't do anything either.  How do I make it exit?

Comment: Does this ssh session launch a process on the remote system which is supposed to keep running after ssh disconnects?

Comment: @Kenster eventually, yes, but I'm currently testing it with some simple commands like `pwd`

Comment: It would be helpful to [edit] your question to include a sample "myscript.sh" contents which produces the problem.

Comment: When bash reads end of your file, it exists and it takes down the session. If there is something interactive inside your script waiting for some other event, you need to find a way to kill other way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing an `exit` statement.

I suspect the reason that the `exit` is necessary is because when you force allocation of a pty, the pty is expecting the input to be a terminal... Reading `EOF` from a terminal doesn't mean '*there is never, ever any more data to come*' the way it does for a pipe / file - it just means that there is '*currently no more input from the user*' - hence the hang... it's waiting for further input.

This input script (`myscript.sh`) 'hangs':

```sh
echo "Hello World..."
```

This doesn't:

```sh
echo "Hello World..."
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of further information, the following script correctly exits after execution even when executed as in the question. If this does not work, please provide an example for which it does not work.

```
echo Hello World
pwd
exit
```